# Angular object return undenfined

Tags: angularjs, object

I have some trouble with object in Angular.

```
var ref = new Wilddog("https://nnkz.wilddogio.com/nightlife/lounges/" + $stateParams.id);    
$scope.post = $wilddogObject(ref);
 console.log($scope.post);
```

When i called this from special service they return me actually object, and i can use them with ng-repeat in my view, but if i wanna use them inside controller like this

```
console.log($scope.post.address)
```

They return me undenfined.

I added image with my object!

[image: This how look object]

Comment: because your object is undefined.

Comment: can show your service code?

Comment: @RameshRajendran but when i calling a console.log($scope.post) they return me this on picture

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `$scope.post = d`

where **d** is the object

try
**`console.log($scope.post.d.address)`**

Comment: ReferenceError: d is not defined

Comment: if($scope.post) {console.log($scope.post.d.address)}

Comment: var obj = $wilddogObject(ref);
obj.$loaded()
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data === obj); // true
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });

Comment: var obj = $wilddogObject(ref); 
obj.$loaded() .then(function(data) {  
 console.log(data === obj); // true    
 $scope.post = data.d? data.d: data
}) 
.catch(function(error) { console.error("Error:", error); });

Answer (score 0):

```
  Thank you guys a lot. That is issue!



var ref = new Wilddog("https://nnkz.wilddogio.com/nightlife/" + 'lounges' + "/" + $stateParams.id);   
        $scope.post = $wilddogObject(ref);
        var obj = $wilddogObject(ref);
          obj.$loaded()
            .then(function(data) {
              console.log(data === obj); // true
            console.log(data.address);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.error("Error:", error);
            });
```